# Kali Linux Kex shows blank screen with just a cursor on Android

Tags: kali-linux, android

I've installed Kali NetHunter on Android using Termux and trying tiger vnc on NetHunter Kex. My problem is when I put in the correct port number and display port, it just shows a blank screen with a working cursor.
Side note: I just solved my issue of postgresql-15 and I thought that might be causing this.
If someone has any opinions on what could resolve this, please help me out. TIA[image: Kex settings]
[image: NetHunter Kex]
[image: Result]